# How to call activity from another application and launch that activity in another app stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have tow apps :

1. madeed app.
2. madeed manager :with launcher activity called `MainActivity` and this Activity has intent filter with this schema: `android:scheme=madeed-manager`.

**madeed** app has a button which direct the user to **madeed manager**. by running this code :

```
String url = "madeed-manager://";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

the code works fine and **`madeed manager`** MainActivity launches. but the problem that **`madeed manager`** activity is added to **madeed** stack . so if the user tab on **madeed** app icon . **madeed manager** will appear. How to let the activity to be launched in another stack.
thanks

EDIT : when i add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag, then it works normally. but i don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Follow 2 Steps:

1: Add an `<intent-filter>` to the third activity with a action:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.package.xxxx.yyyyy.SOMETHING"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

2: Start Intent

startActivity(new Intent("com.package.xxxx.yyyyy.SOMETHING"));

```
enter code here
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but it has the same problem . when i tab on "madeed" app icon it shows madeed manager activity.